# How to restore KDE 5 panel?

Tags: fedora, kde, plasma, kde5, plasma5

I'm running Fedora and I recently upgraded to 27. Now I just did another update and rebooted, but suddenly my panel/taskbar is gone. I customized it quite a bit and even assigned keyboard shortcuts. I really don't want to set it up again.

How can I tell KDE to restore the panel that I had before? Where is it stored?

I already tried `kquitapp plasmashell && kstart plasmashell`, but the output was just:

```
trying to show an empty dialog
kstart(6187) main: Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended 
fedora@localhost:~$ org.kde.kcoreaddons: Expected JSON property "X-Plasma-ContainmentCategories" to be a string list. Treating it as a list with a single entry: "panel" org.kde.plasma.desktop.appmenubar
org.kde.kcoreaddons: Expected JSON property "X-Plasma-ContainmentCategories" to be a string list. Treating it as a list with a single entry: "panel" org.kde.plasma.desktop.defaultPanel
org.kde.kcoreaddons: Expected JSON property "X-Plasma-ContainmentCategories" to be a string list. Treating it as a list with a single entry: "panel" org.kde.plasma.desktop.emptyPanel
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:147:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:147:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:288:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:288:17: QML Text: Binding loop detected for property "width"
```

and never finished.